# 404 Not Found: Requested route ('livesyncdownload.ng.bluemix.net') does not exist

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am trying to download Bluemix Live Sync. But, it's showing this error:

> 404 Not Found: Requested route ('livesyncdownload.ng.bluemix.net') does not exist.

Comment: The URL route is down - please try again later. Apologies for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an internal error with the application which has now been resolved. This is working as expected now, please try again.